# How to get the closest child of the clicked div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div named `#container` and have many children which have a common class of `.timescalebase`. My requirement is when I click in my parent `div` I want the nearest child. I can't use the child id for click event because its width is `0px`.

```
<div id="container" style="width: 70%; margin-top: 15px; position: absolute;">
    <div class="timescalebase" id="1"></div>
    <div class="timescalebase" id="2"></div>
    <div class="timescalebase" id="3"></div>
</div>
```

```js
 $(document).on('click', '#container', function (e) {
    base = $(this).closest(".timescalebase")
    baseid = base.attr('id');
});
```

Comment: In such a case, you can't do it.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'closest child'? Can you not just put the `click` event handler directly on the `#container .timescalebase` elements and use `this` within the handler to refer to the element?

Comment: then, is there any suggestion please

Comment: Do you mean the child, which is nearest to the location where the click event happened?

Comment: `id=1;` is invalid HTML.

Comment: yes  , nearest to the location where the click event happened

Comment: How are the child divs positioned? A working example of the HTML (including any CSS) would help a lot here.

Comment: if all the children have width `0px` it means they are all not visible to user. What is the purpose of the children?

Comment: yp. this click event is for give the width

Comment: ok. i understand i can't get output like this way. i will think another method. thanks all :)

Comment: @manup, Closest will look for closet parent and not for child, you need to find child, you can refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is the solution;

```js
var ruler;
var nearestDiv;
$("#container").on("click",function (e) {
  ruler = 10000000;
  $(".timescalebase").each(function(i, a) {
    if (Math.abs(e.pageY - $(a).offset().top) < ruler) {
      ruler = Math.abs(e.pageY - $(a).offset().top);
      nearestDiv = a;
    }
  });

  var baseid = $(nearestDiv).attr("id");
  alert(baseid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width: 70%; margin-top: 15px;">
  <div class="timescalebase" id="a1">A....</div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="timescalebase" id="a2">B....</div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div class="timescalebase" id="a3">C....</div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `offset()` method to find the position of all the child elements and compare to pageX and pageY of the mouse click event.

http://api.jquery.com/offset/

http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/

http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$(document).on('click', '#container', function (e) {
    var closestChild = $(this).find(".timescalebase:first");
});
```

Comment: No... I guess. The OP is looking for ... Read it again.

Comment: What is meant by nearest child?

Comment: When you click on that random div, some div should be near your clicked area right? Looks like this question is crazy and unanswerable.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought the same way. Question is not clarified and misleading.

Comment: By the way all child are nearest to the parent. hahahah

Comment: Yes, it is better you delete this answer till you get a clarity. See the comments in the question. Esp by Rory.

Comment: LoL. That's true.

Answer (score 0):

Closest from [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) :For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up **through its ancestors** in the DOM tree.

Closest will look for closet parent not child, you need to find child.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anilk/xa15bgjs/) to get first child;

```
<div id="container" style="width: 70%; margin-top: 15px; position: absolute;">
click on me
    <div class="timescalebase" id='1'></div>
    <div class="timescalebase" id='2'></div>
    <div class="timescalebase" id='3'></div>
</div>
 $(document).on('click', '#container', function (e) {
    var base = $(this).find(".timescalebase").first();
    var baseid = base.attr('id');
    alert(baseid);
});
```

`closest()` selects the first element that matches the selector, up from the DOM tree, you will be getting the container div itself.

Answer (score -1):

In such case you can use code below :

```
   $("#container").on("click", function ()
     {
      //if required first div
    alert($(this).find(".timescalebase:eq(0)").attr("id"));
      //if required second div
    alert($(this).find(".timescalebase:eq(1)").attr("id"));
      //if required third div
    alert($(this).find(".timescalebase:eq(2)").attr("id"));
    });
```